# Bash script to watch for file system changes, with delay before executing a backup script

Tags: shell-script, backup

I have a need to monitor a directory tree for any file changes. On changes I'd like to trigger a backup script (essentially a git commit, but including a database dump).

As I expect there will likely be more changes within a relatively short timeframe I'd like to wait for n seconds before executing the backup script to reduce the number of commits.

To sum up my requirements:

- monitor a directory recursively for file changes
- grace period of n seconds for further changes before execution of backup
- any changes occurring during backup run must not be lost

---

Using javascript I would do something like the following on any file change:

```
if (timeout) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
timeout = setTimeout(callback, 60000);
```

I am not clear how to replicate such behavior using a bash script. My current approach is as follows:

*watch.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait \
  --recursive \
  --monitor \
  --event attrib,modify,move,create,delete \
  --format %e \
  /usr/src/app/html/themes/ |

while read events; do
  flock -n /var/run/backup-watch.lockfile -c /usr/src/scripts/watch-backup.sh
done
```

*watch-backup.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait for more changes to happen
sleep 60

# run script
/usr/src/scripts/commit-changes.sh
```

---

This has the waiting component but will ignore any changes happening while the commit-changes.sh script is running.

Alternatives:

- I considered using a node js script, but the node fs watch command does not allow recursive directory watching, so this is not an option.
- Cron could be an alternative but I'd prefer to watch for changes instead of running on a schedule. The backup script will generate a new commit each time due to the db-dump being part of it. While I could make the backup more complicated by checking if there are any other changes but the db-dump I'd like to keep it simple there.

Comment: What distro are you using? The redhat line has auditd, which can be configured to watch files for changes and perform actions in response.

Comment: @Centimane: Ubuntu (14.04 at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd)

> Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify or fsevents). It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes.

Comment: Looks like a viable option, but I'd rather like not to add another dependency to the system.